# Meaning of InterpolationOrder -> All for multidimensional interpolation

Tags: interpolation, implementation-details

What specific method does [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) use for unstructured multi-dimensional data when we set `InterpolationOrder -> All`?  Documentation links are welcome.

Example 2D data:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {20, 3}];
```

When the data points are not on a grid, the only allowed settings for `InterpolationOrder` are `1` and `All`, according to the error message issued when trying something else.

With `1`, it is clear how it works: a Delaunay triangulation is computed and linear interpolation is done over each triangle.

But how does `All` work, and what determines the actual order that is chosen?

```
if = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> All];

if["InterpolationOrder"]
(* 5 *)

Show[
 Plot3D[if[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point[data]}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Dunno, but the return value of `if["InterpolationOrder"]` that I get is `{9223372036854775806, 9223372036854775806}`. Oo

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Oops ... It seems I tried this with M12.0 (it's available in the cloud).

Comment: Anyways, very good questions. I am also curious what works there in the background.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher If this gives a hint, starting from 4 data points, the first 3 data point counts get interpolation order 2, then the next 4 get 3, then the next 5 get 4, etc.

Comment: That sounds as if they were using straight-forward global interpolation by a polynomial of degree up to `n`. Then you have `Binomial[n, 2]` basis functions. In that case, this should become nasty for higher point counts due to Runge's phenomenon and ill-conditioned linear systems (for solving for the coefficients). So I presume, that they will switch to another method when the point count becomes larger...

Comment: In this context, I just want to point to the "Obtuse" package for doing multidimensional interpolation on scattered data points. You can download it (for free) from http://www.familydahl.se/mathematica/.
The package implements five different methods: the Delaunay interpolation method, the Voronoi interpolation method, the Shepard interpolation method, the RBF interpolation method and the ObtuseAngle interpolation method. For the ObtuseAngle method the InterpolationOrder can be set to 0, 1, 2, and 3, but not to All. The number of dimensions is not limited.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is code that has been written many moons ago... here is an example:

```
d = {{0.4138352728412389, 0.02365673668161028}, {0.5509946389658635, 
    0.7254061374370833}, {0.14521595926324116, 
    0.6528630823305817}, {0.48768962246740544, 
    0.22066264105073286}, {0.8309710560928056, 
    0.3496966364384875}, {0.4553589220242207, 
    0.9383446951847001}, {0.2126873262146789, 
    0.017512080396716145}, {0.967248982535015, 
    0.6211273372083488}, {0.3548669163916416, 
    0.737108322193581}, {0.6919974835480842, 0.9322403408098401}};
f = {{0.9953617542392983}, {0.14070666511222818}, \
{0.285662339441511}, {0.7988192898854105}, {0.3592646208757597}, \
{0.565455746009103}, {0.22110814761432618}, {0.2735048548887764}, \
{0.08792348530403005}, {0.4202942851818514}};
data = Join[d, f, 2];
if = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> All];
if[0.5, 0.5]

0.268157
```

And here is roughly what it does:

```
dt = Transpose[d];
temp = Join[{ConstantArray[1., {Length[d]}]}, dt, dt[[{1}]]^2, 
   dt[[{1}]]*dt[[{2}]], dt[[{2}]]^2, dt[[{1}]]^3, 
   dt[[{1}]]^2*dt[[{2}]], dt[[{1}]]*dt[[{2}]]^2, dt[[{2}]]^3];
p = Transpose[temp];
ls = LinearSolve[p];
vals = ls[Flatten[f]];
System`Private`EvaluateListPolynomial[vals, {0.5, 0.5}]

0.268157
```