# Multi-dimensional interpolation of unstructured array returns unevaluated

Tags: interpolation

Interpolation should work fine on an unstructured array of machine numbers with interpolation order 1. However, when both the arguments and output are multidimensional, it doesn't evaluate. The first five interpolations below work fine, whereas the last one returns unevaluated.

```
array1 = {#, RandomReal[]} & /@ Tuples[Range@4, 2];
array2 = {#, RandomReal[1, 2]} & /@ Range@4;
array3 = {#, RandomReal[1, 2]} & /@ Tuples[Range@4, 2];
Interpolation@array1
Interpolation@array2
Interpolation@array3
Interpolation[N@Delete[array1, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
Interpolation[N@Delete[array2, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
Interpolation[N@Delete[array3, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

Comment: `InterpolationOrder -> All`

Comment: @cvgmt Interesting. I don't find anything in the documentation that explains why that's needed or why it would work. Regardless, it gives outrageous values. `Interpolation[N@Delete[array3, 1], InterpolationOrder -> All][2, 2.01]` can yield `{-8.34406*10^9, -4.49641*10^10}`

Comment: Related: [Meaning of InterpolationOrder -> All for multidimensional interpolation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/195279/27951).